# Remove underlined hyperlink in portlet

Tags: css, hyperlink, plone

Working on plone and am just getting experience with it. In my portlet I am currently editing a static text portlet to look like an RSS feed (so I can have some customization with my news items). I've gotten the format to work perfectly - with the exception of removing the underline from the hyperlink. I've tried using methods from all the different forums with CSS and HTML formatting...it's not working. Anyone able to help?

Comment: What did you try with CSS? It's just a question of finding the right CSS selector, as Matheus is trying to show you.

Answer (score 2):

Use FireFox + FireBug to find which css property is used on portlet hyperlink.
Probably you wrote a property too general and one more specific is used.
Take a look:

```
....
<style>
    .portlet a {text-decoration: underline;}
    a {text-decoration: none;}
</style>
<div class="portlet">
    <a href="#">1</a>
</div>
....
```

Hyperlink will be underline because the first css property has a more specific "path".